# Why is screencapture taking the screenshot of the desktop image and not the windows on top in Catalina?

Tags: macos, command-line, screen-capture, catalina

Why is `screencapture` command only takes the screenshot of the desktop image and not the windows on top in Catalina?  I keep on trying on Catalina compared to High Sierra or Mojave where this is not the case with `screencapture` command.

Here is the link to the shell script on my Github: https://github.com/shyamalschandra/screenshot2speech The relevant command is

```
screencapture -s ~/Downloads/screen.png
```

http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/11/take-screen-shots-terminal-mac-os-x/

Comment: you might find `man screencapture` helpful. flags like -w and -W and -o are helpful.

Comment: @ankii I know the `man screencapture`.  Nothing has changed AFAIK between Mojave and Catalina.

Comment: What was the exact command you used ? And which app was in focus ?

Comment: @ankii : Here is the link to the shell script on my Github: https://github.com/shyamalschandra/screenshot2speech

Comment: I have the same issue when Finder or Preview is the foreground app. The answer from Nic below sheds some light but not fully. My personal workaround is to let **some other app** on the top, put Finder or Preview in between the top app and the desktop, and then select the area of Finder or Preview.

Answer (score 5):

I got same issue and finally found out what was wrong.
Go to System Preference>Security & Privacy>Screen Recording, And give them permission to capture.

[image]

Comment: I was having this problem suddenly where screen capture (CMD+Shift+4) was recording the background. When I went to the Screen Recording Privacy Menu there was no Terminal. Once I added it, the problem was fixed. Reeeally annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with macOS Catalina, applications *must* be granted the `ScreenCapture` permission before they can capture any content from the screen. [How do I configure Screen Recording permission on macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384228/18101) Normally when you run a command like `screencapture` you should be presented with an authorization prompt like this one:

[image]

If you don't see this prompt, you might need to reset your screen recording permissions for the Terminal application you are using: [How do I reset Screen Recording permission on macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384230/18101)

```
tccutil reset ScreenCapture com.apple.Terminal
```

Comment: I have the same issue and noticed this permission restrain. After a full reset of screen recording permission, I still only get desktop image if the Finder or Preview is the foreground app. The screen recording pop-up message doesn't show either if Finder or Preview is the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `screencapture -s ~/Downloads/screen.png` [source](https://github.com/shyamalschandra/screenshot2speech) where `-s` is for

> Only allow mouse selection mode.

try `-w`. It will show a camera icon and wait for you to select a window. Hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel the process.

```
screencapture -w ~/Downloads/screen.png
```

> -w      Only allow window selection mode.

I cannot say why `-s` doesn't work, but on Mojave, the `man` page says

> The **screencapture** utility is not very well documented to date.  A list of
>        options follows.

Comment: However, now when I saw other posts of scripting.  you might need to get the window id, instead of manual response every time.

Comment: I need the manual two screen coordinates because then, I can extract the textual content for speech synthesis.

Comment: I don't understand as I never used the command. What do you suggest I look for ?